# ORA-00926: missing VALUES keyword on C#

Tags: c#, oracle

Some body help me. I can't fix this error because i don't know where it error. I was debuged but not success.And error is ORA-00926: missing VALUES keyword on C# after cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

```
string strInsert = @"Insert into INFOR_STUDENT(IdStudent, NameStudent, NameClass, IdClass, BirthStudent, SexStudent)  :IdStudent, :NameStudent, :NameClass, Select IdClass from Infor_Class where NameClass = :NameClass, :BirthStudent, :SexStudent";                

            OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();
            //cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.CommandText = strInsert;
            cmd.Connection = connIns;


            OracleParameter idClassParam = cmd.Parameters.Add("IdStudent", OracleDbType.Varchar2,
                ParameterDirection.Input);
            idClassParam.Value = tbxIdStudent.Text;


            OracleParameter nameClassParam = cmd.Parameters.Add("NameStudent", OracleDbType.Varchar2,
                ParameterDirection.Input);
            nameClassParam.Value = tbxNameStudent.Text;


            OracleParameter Si_soParam = cmd.Parameters.Add("NameClass", OracleDbType.Varchar2,
                ParameterDirection.Input);
            Si_soParam.Value = ddListClass.Text;


            OracleParameter birthStudent = cmd.Parameters.Add("BirthStudent", OracleDbType.Date,
                ParameterDirection.Input);
            birthStudent.Value = DateTime.ParseExact(tbxBirthSt.Text, "dd/mm/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);


            OracleParameter sexStudent = cmd.Parameters.Add("SexStudent", OracleDbType.Varchar2,
                ParameterDirection.Input);
            sexStudent.Value = ddListSex.Text;

            int row = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error message suggests, try to add `VALUES` keyword on your `strInsert` after you specify all the column names of the table:

```
string strInsert = @"Insert into INFOR_STUDENT(IdStudent, NameStudent, NameClass, IdClass, BirthStudent, SexStudent) VALUES (:IdStudent, :NameStudent, :NameClass, Select IdClass from Infor_Class where NameClass = :NameClass, :BirthStudent, :SexStudent)";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string strInsert = @"Insert into INFOR_STUDENT(IdStudent, NameStudent, NameClass, IdClass, BirthStudent, SexStudent) Values  :IdStudent, :NameStudent, :NameClass, Select IdClass from Infor_Class where NameClass = :NameClass, :BirthStudent, :SexStudent";
```

You forgor to add the keyword values to your query